# Django datatable server side processing having problems with djang templating engine

Tags: jquery, django, datatables

I am having trouble with django-datatables server side processing.

The server side processing works but it seems like the

{% if %} {% endif %} statements wasn't being read.

Here a screenshot sample when i commented out the serverside=True.

[image: As you can see it was working fine]

but when i uncomment the serverside=True

[image: When the server side is turned on. the value of status is not shown. because it was enclosed with an if else statement in my templates]

[image: Screenshot of my tables]

here are the screen shot of my listview and datatablesview

[image: listview]

[image: datablesview]

here is my models.py

[image: models]

Comment: Hi, @michael ababao. Could you provide your view? I guess there's some inconsistency there.

Comment: Hi @eliakin costa.U mean the view for rendering the list or the view for datatables?

Comment: the view within your `views.py` @michael ababao

Comment: ohh sorry. i have updated my post with the screenshot of my views

Comment: Is `pm_done` a field within your model ? Where did it came from? Could you provider your models as well? @michael ababao

Comment: yes it is a field. updated the post, added my models

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203409/discussion-between-eliakin-costa-and-michael-ababao).